# Remove apostrophe from wordpress posts URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, permalinks, apostrophe

The issues we have 'long listed posts' which contains 's in permalinks , we regularly update the wordpress so no longer now access the 's permalinks , when we open 's urls's it'll show the 404 page , these happen with only old  posts for new 's is removed wordpress automatically.

i.e 
Orginal Url : 
http://localhost/test-new/world%E2%80%99s-most-popular-new-test-company-with-big-impactswe/

wants to Replace with

http://localhost/procument-new/worlds-most-popular-new-gen-companies-with-big-impacts/

in short we wants to remove 's from permalinks

suggest me , and thank you in advance .

Comment: I think you lost some characters here, what should be before `'s`? If it's a special character put it inside `code`

Comment: hi , thank you 

this is my old URL : localhost/wp-test/world%E2%80%99s-most-popular-new-gen-companies-with-big-impacts/

we have 1000+ urls which have 's in urls

Now , problem is what that latest wordpress not taking 's means , suppose i write post title Lorem's slug will generate lorems , we have update the latest wordpress so , our old urls no longer show , it's display 404 error , but we wants to list it in site

for that we wants to remove 's from permalinks/url so post will show . hope you undstand what i want u explain , thanks

Comment: simple , suppose url : localhost/wp-test/world%E2%80%99s-most-popular-new-gen-companies-with-big-impact‌​s/ than redirect it to localhost/wp-test/worlds-most-popular-new-gen-companies-with-big-impact‌​s/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Resolved , actually i did mistake i put the code in  but it is not need wrap inside

RewriteRule ^(.*)’(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)'(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress convert special characters into entities, you are trying to open it directly with `'` **(apostrophe)** , it will show `404`, you should go the

`Settings ==> Permalinks` and update it.

Comment: posts link is coming from social sites where in pasts shared , while in wordpress all posts slug are updated , so when users come with old post slug which no longer available in wordpress so, it's showing 404 , but we wants to redirect it with new updated posts slug which not contain word's but its words now , you getting me !!!